# How to make changes by using onChange using <select> in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm making an app that uses a dropdown menu like:

```
            <select name="color">
              <option value="red" onChange={this.func}>Red</option>
              <option value="blue" onChange={this.func}>
                Blue
              </option>
            </select>
```

However, the onChange function is not working. The function given is:

```
  func = () => {
    console.log("Color");
  };
```

I'm wondering why is this not working? What should be done to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work, because selects fire onChange events, and options don't. You need move the onChange event handling to the `<select/>`:

```
 <select name="color" onChange={this.func}>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
 </select>

// and for your func:
func = (event) => {
  //event.target.value contains the selected option value, e.g. "red"
  console.log("Color: ", event.target.value);
};
```